# How to make a program restart on command in python

Tags: python

### I have the following program:

```
x = int(input('How many rows? - '))
y = int(input('How many max per row? - '))
z = int(input('How many min per row - '))
string = str('•')

lines = y # Makes a copy of y that can be seperatly changed

while True:

    if z > y: # Makes sure than "max per row" > "min per row"
        print('Please make sure that \"max per row\" is greater than \"min per row\"')
        break

    for n in range(int(x)): # Run the specified amount of times

        if int(lines) > int(z): # If 'max per row' < 'min per row'
            for more in range(int(y)): # Print '•'*'y' untill it reaches 'min per row'
                print(str(string)*int(lines))
                lines -= 1

        else:
            for less in range(int(y)): # Print '•'*'y' untill it reaches 'max per row'
                print(str(string)*int(lines))
                lines += 1
```

I want to `restart` the program `if z > y`. Currently I stop the program with a `break` function, I wish for it to `re-run`. *(see line 12)*

Comment: Start by writing a function such as `do_thing` and a `main` entry-point function. Re-call` do_thing` from `main` when `z > y`, such as in a while-True loop like you have now.

Comment: You should wrap the whole lot in a `while` loop.

Comment: @quamrana I already ahve everything in a `while` loop. But `break` only stops the program, I want it to run again

Comment: I meant that you do *not* have *everything* in a `while` loop. You should wrap the whole lot in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by putting the check for `if z <= y:` inside a loop that breaks if it's true nad continues to ask if it's false. Also improved code by ading a sleep function.

```py
from time import sleep

while True:
    y = int(input('How many max per row? - '))
    z = int(input('How many min per row - '))

    if z <= y:
        break

    print('Please make sure that "max per row" is greater than "min per row"')

string = ('•')

lines = y # Makes a copy of y that can be seperatly changed
lines = int(lines)
runTimes = y - z

while True: # Just keeps making waves
 
    if lines > z: # If 'max per row' > 'min per row'
        for more in range(runTimes): # Print '•'*'y' untill it reaches 'min per row'
            finalString = string*lines
            print(finalString)
            lines -= 1
            sleep(0.035)
            
    else:
        for less in range(runTimes): # Print '•'*'y' untill it reaches 'max per row'
            finalString = string*lines
            print(finalString)
            lines += 1
            sleep(0.035)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create a function

```py
def main():
    x = int(input('How many rows? - '))
    y = int(input('How many max per row? - '))
    z = int(input('How many min per row - '))
    string = str('•')

    lines = y # Makes a copy of y that can be seperatly changed

    while True:

        if z > y: # Makes sure than "max per row" > "min per row"
            print('Please make sure that \"max per row\" is greater than \"min per row\"')
            break

        for n in range(int(x)): # Run the specified amount of times

            if int(lines) > int(z): # If 'max per row' < 'min per row'
                for more in range(int(y)): # Print '•'*'y' untill it reaches 'min per row'
                    print(str(string)*int(lines))
                    lines -= 1

            else:
                for less in range(int(y)): # Print '•'*'y' untill it reaches 'max per row'
                    print(str(string)*int(lines))
                    lines += 1

while True:
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want to do:

```
while True:
    x = int(input('How many rows? - '))
    y = int(input('How many max per row? - '))
    z = int(input('How many min per row - '))

    if z <= y:
        break

    print('Please make sure that "max per row" is greater than "min per row"')

string = '•'

lines = y # Makes a copy of y that can be seperately changed

for n in range(x): # Run the specified amount of times

    if lines > z: # If 'max per row' < 'min per row'
        for more in range(y):   # Print '•'*'y' until it reaches 'min per row'
            print(string * lines)
            lines -= 1

    else:
        for less in range(y):   # Print '•'*'y' until it reaches 'max per row'
            print(string * lines)
            lines += 1
```

PS: You don’t have to use `str()` if a value already *is* a string. Similarly for `int()`. You already convert to integer at the very beginning with `int(input(...))`, so the variables already contain integer values, so you don’t have to use `int()` again later on.

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I want to do. But please explain to me, *how* does the part you changed actually *work*? I really want to understand it so I can solve similar problems in the future!

Comment: I suggest you read a good Python tutorial for beginners that explains how control structures work (in particular `if`, `while`, `break`). There are lots of tutorials on the web; just use Google or another search engine. Stackoverflow is not the place to teach things like that.

Comment: I now have this code: https://pastebin.com/jMdriKdx

How do I make it not print the empty space that it prints inbetween every wave? https://imgur.com/a/9Hjntab

Comment: This is unrelated to the original question. Please submit a new question if you think it is appropriate for StackOverflow. And, again, I strongly recommend you take a good Python tutorial for beginners first. It will answer this and probably a lot of other questions of yours. (Also, pastebin and imgur are blocked in my web proxy, so I can’t help you that way.)